# WinRT, TextBox's focus, weird behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime, focus

in one of my WinRT App's Views, I'd like the `BottomAppBar` to be displayed when a `TextBox`loses focus. I played with the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events with which I can manually change the `IsOpen` property of the `BottomAppBar` accordingly.

Problem is, when the `BottomAppBar` is open, if the user clicks on the `TextBox`, the `BottomAppBar` is closed (standard AppBar behavior), but the `TextBox` is not focused (even though the user clicked right on it). The user needs to focus the `TextBox` again to be able to type something again.

If I hook myself up in the `Closed` event of the `BottomAppBar` to try and programmatically set the focus to the `TextBox`, it shortly becomes focused, but loses the focus right away and instead, its ScrollViewer gets focused.

Any idea why the `TextBox` loses the focus the second time?
Any idea how I can do what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your `BottomAppBar` gets closed when you tap out of it and on the `ScrollViewer` and setting the focus to your `TextBox` gets overriden by the focus being set to the `ScrollViewer` right after that. If you only ever want focus to be on the `TextBox` - you could disable focus from `ScrollViewer`. You could also try to set the focus after a delay (either with `await Task.Delay(50);` or with `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(() => /*set focus)` so it might get set after the `ScrollViewer` gets focus or handle `GotFocus` on the `ScrollViewer` and set the focus back to the `TextBox` when you want it to keep the focus. Finally make sure that the `TextBox` can get focus at all.

Comment: Holly sh*! it worked >_< Since I don't have direct access to the ScrollViewer (it is implicitely set on the TextBox via `ScrollViewer.*ScrollBarVisibility`), I tried the async approach you mentioned and it worked like a charm (both of them do). Thanks mate!